# Why is a string printed although print isn't used?

Tags: python

This is an example program from the Python book that I am using to learn. What does the `message +=` line signify? And how does it print that statement even though we've never used a print there?

This works as expected and returns `$number is too high` or `$number is too low`. But how does it do so even without `print` statement?

And what does `message += str(guess) + ....` do here, given that we've declared message as an empty string in the beginning (`message = ""`)?

```
import random # We cover random numbers in the
rng = random.Random() 

number = rng.randrange(1, 1000) 

guesses = 0
message = ""

while True:
    guess = int(input(message + "\nGuess my number between 1 and 1000:")) 
    guesses += 1
    if guess > number:
        message += str(guess) + " is too high.\n" 
    elif guess < number:
        message += str(guess) + " is too low.\n" 
    else:
        break
input("\n\nGreat, you got it in "+str(guesses)+" guesses!\n\n")
```

I tried using message like in the above program in one of my other scripts and it doesn't print statement like it does in the above program.

Comment: because `message` is passed as argument to input, so it's printed as input prompt.

Comment: Only one question per question, please. The string addition question is a common FAQ anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `input()` includes `message` in its prompt.

Addition of strings concatenates them in Python. `"ab" + "cd"` produces `"abcd"`. Similarly, `message += "stuff"` adds `"stuff"` to the end of the variable's earlier value. If it was the empty string before, `"" + "stuff"` produces simply `"stuff"`.

The operator `+=` is an increment assignment; `a += b` is short for `a = a + b`. (Some people also dislike the longer expression because it is mathematically implausible unless at least one of the values is zero; but `=` does not have its mathematical semantics anywhere else in Python, either.)